# Not able to sign into Uber on iOS with Web Security Gateway in place. Need help identifying URL to whitelist

Tags: uber-api

We are using an app which acts as a Web Security Gateway and it's blocking users from logging into the Uber app. Normally I can capture web traffic and whitelist the URL, but I can't capture traffic within the Uber app. I've whitelisted *.uber.com * but it's still not working. Does anyone know what URLs Uber uses? I've called, but they were not able to provide me with any details.

Comment: Is this a browser app or a phone app?

Comment: app on the iphone

Comment: You use your security gateway to capture the web traffic?

Comment: It's unclear to me why you would be able to capture traffic on any other app, but not the Uber one.

Comment: The vendor has an iphone app, so it filters all the traffic from the iphone. The problem is that I can only do a packet capture on the browser traffic, but not from an app. Some apps work and some don't. For example, I had to whitelist mail-attachment.googleusercontent.com for attachments to open within the gmail app. For Uber, I suspect the problem is that the auth redirect is being blocked.